# subtract the weight of the largest edge

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs, dijkstras-algorithm

I have an oriented and weighted graph, and I need to find the cheapest route from source to destination.
Now I have a source node A and a destination node B the cheapest path is given to me by the sum of the weight of the arches to which I have to subtract the discount, the discount is given to me by the weight of the largest arch that I encounter during the journey.

so for example

in the result the first number indicates the sum of the weight of the arches while the second number indicates the discount that I am going to subtract, i.e. the arch with the greatest weight that I encounter in my path

```
0-> 2-> 3-> 4 = 10-5

0-> 1-> 3-> 4 = 11-5

0-> 1-> 4 = 16-12 (this is the solution)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that the distance is always > 0. The solution still doesn't require revisiting a node later, so Djikstra should be usable.

Idea:
the weight of a path is always going to be (sum of all edge weights of edges in the path) - (highest weight of edge in path)

Djikstra guarantuees we always know the shortest path to a node. If we also store the discount of the current path to each node, we can know whether an edge counts as (weight of the edge) or (current discount [ because edge weight - new discount + old discount = old discount]), and use that as the weight wherever Djikstra needs it.

Pseudocode (adapted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)):

```
function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
       
       for each vertex v in Graph.Vertices:
           dist[v] ← INFINITY
           prev[v] ← UNDEFINED
           discount[v] ← UNDEFINED 
           add v to Q
       dist[source] ← 0
       discount[source] ← 0
       
       while Q is not empty:
          u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]
          remove u from Q
          
          for each neighbor v of u still in Q:
              if Graph.Edges(u, v) > discount[u]:
                  alt ← dist[u] + discount[u]
                  if alt < dist[v]:
                      dist[v] ← alt
                      prev[v] ← u
                      discount[v] ← Graph.Edges(u,v)
              else:
                  alt ← dist[u] + Graph.Edges(u, v)
                  if alt < dist[v]:
                      dist[v] ← alt
                      prev[v] ← u
                      discount[v] ← discount[u]

      return dist[], prev[]
```

Comment: but how can I analyze every single path from node A and node B? djistra does not give me back only the path that has minimal weight at each step?

Comment: @ant0982 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm In step 3 of the algorithm is where we adapt - we change what is considered "tentative distance". For each node we also store, in addition to the predecessor and tentative distance, the "tentative discount" which is always going to be the highest edge value on the path we took to get the tentative distance. See the pseudocode on the wiki page.

Comment: if you could post some pseudocode of your idea that would be great. Because I didn't understand how at every step I can control this thing. should i change the relax?

Comment: @ant0982 Here you go

Comment: god bless you my friend thank you very much

Comment: I tried to implement this solution but it doesn't always seem to work there are some inputs that create problems for me, could you explain why?

Comment: @ant0982 No, not without you telling me what inputs cause problems.

Comment: if you check this input i tried it doesn't work https://pastebin.com/j6ZkxYQN

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to solve this using a common trick: rather than altering the algorithm, alter the graph.

"Subtracting the weight of the largest edge" is the same as "setting the weight of the largest edge to 0". In other words, we want to find the shortest path where one edge is allowed to have weight 0.

To solve this, create a second copy of the graph.  Let's write `a`, `b` for nodes in the original graph, and `a'`, `b'` for nodes in the new graph.  Then for every edge `a --> b` in the original graph, add a new edge `a --> b'` from the original graph to the new graph with edge-weight 0.  Then run Dijkstra's as normal.

That's it! The path will only be able to move from the old graph to the new one with cost 0 one time, encoding the fact that only one edge can be changed to 0.

Comment: if you have an input graph with many nodes and arcs copying a graph can be very expensive

Comment: @ant0982 It's `O(V+E)` which is cheaper than Dijkstra's, meaning the asymptotic runtime is the same. But if this algorithm is truly a bottleneck in some real-world process, you could generate the second graph dynamically as part of the algorithm.

Comment: This has the advantage that you can use any Djikstra implementation or any other shortest path algorithm. Also, if I understand correctly, this only doubles the size of the graph, which is less than what I expected a solution that alters the graph would do.